# Remove unnecessary space in CSS3 columns

Tags: html, css

I'm experimenting with the latest columns feature in CSS3. Each `ul` has varying heights, and I want them to have equal margins **above** and **below**. At the moment, because one `ul` is much longer than the rest, it is pushing the second row down. Is it possible for the longest `ul` to not force so much space beneath it?

http://jsfiddle.net/t5ng3/

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: grey;
    max-width: 600px;
    -webkit-column-width: 50%;
}

ul {
    background-color: orange;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 20%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see how you're using columns here, nor do I understand what space you're trying to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of white space, which will cause normally a `4px` offset, inorder to solve this, there are various ways, the cheap one is to use `margin-left: -4px;` but this will fail if the `font-size > 100%`, another way is to use `font-size: 0;` on the parent element, and the last one is to take out the indentation/white space from the source by sticking up the `ul` elements..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t5ng3/1/)

You can also `float` your elements to the `left` but for this it will be better if you wrap them inside a container `div`/`section` element.

---

Now I am not sure whether you are aware of this or not but you might like to have a look at [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) property which will do a similar job without breaking yourself the `ul` elements..

Comment: Ah, my next question would be: why is this not splitting the columns in 3: http://jsfiddle.net/t5ng3/3/ — I'm using `-webkit-column-count: 3; -webkit-column-width: 30%:`

Comment: And my last question... How can I get those columns to fill 30% of the wrapper? It seems to be ignoring that completely.

Comment: You legend. Thanks. I'm not sure why this isn't splitting into 4 columns, however: http://jsfiddle.net/t5ng3/10/

Comment: You beautiful Alien! How come no inline block is required?

Comment: @tmyie you are using `column-count` property, using that will slice up the childrens into 4 parts, so you don't need `inline-block`, if you are using `floats/inline-block` you don't need `column-count`, also, you won't need `width: 100%;` on `ul` as it's a block level element by default

Comment: The `column-width` property does *not* require a `column-count`: http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/CcGlE

Answer (score 1):

The "columns" you're seeing are purely the result of your lists being inline-block, not because you're using column-width.  The column-width property does not appear to work as you would expect with a percentage value.

If you want exactly 2 columns, then you would use `column-count: 2` rather than `column-width: 50%`.

http://jsfiddle.net/t5ng3/12/

```
.wrapper {
    background-color: grey;
    max-width: 600px;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
    columns: 2;
}
ul {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

If the child elements should not be split across columns, then the `break-inside` property is what you're looking for rather than trying to use `display: inline-block`.

```
ul {
    background-color: orange;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* old name */
    page-break-inside: avoid; /* Firefox uses non-standard property */
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

You may wish to remove the top margin on the first element:

```
ul:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because there is space between `</ul>` and `<ul>`. `inline-block` elements leave space.

Removeing space i.e. writing `</ul><ul>` will resolve your problem.
[**Updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/t5ng3/2/)